# PgSQL trim whole string at end, not every characters

Tags: postgresql

i'm trying to rebuild relations in my DB. I need to "repair" some strings that are stored badly in my table named **city_list**.

The data:

"Berlin"

"London "

"Kijev&nbsp"

"Poznan&nbsp"

I used pgsql function *rtrim(string text [, characters text])* in that way:

```
UPDATE city_list SET city_name=RTrim(city_name);
UPDATE city_list SET city_name=RTrim(city_name, '&nbsp;');
```

Now I have:

"Berlin"

"Londo"

"Kijev"

"Pozna"

Is there way to force rtrim to cut whole " " string from end not every single characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace()`.

The `trim()` function's second argument is the full list of chars to be trimmed.

Comment: A "normal" `replace()` should be enough. No need for a regex here.